# Count value inside array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array data like below:

```
$data =array(
'6' => array(
    '00:01' => array(
        'area1' => array(
            '0' => array(),
            '1' => array(),
            '2' => array(),
            ),
        'area2' => array(
            '0' => array(),
            '1' => array(),
            '2' => array(),
            )
         )
      )
  )
```

Now I want to count the number elements inside the area key. The output should be:

```
$data = array(
'6' => array(
    '00:01' => array(
        'area1'=> '3',
        'area2'=> '3',
    )
  )
)
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: foreach + `count()` and done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. But the idea is always the same. You need to iterate this array. That's all.

Here's an example based on `array_map` function

```
$counts = array_map(function($item) {
    return array_map(function($hour) {
        return array_map(function($area) {
            return count($area);
        }, $hour);  
    }, $item);
}, $data);
```

`$counts` content is:

```
array(1) {
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["00:01"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["area1"]=>
      int(3)
      ["area2"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
}
```

You can do that also with `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could simply iterate it, like so:

```
<?php $data =array(
'6' => array(
    '00:01' => array(
        'area1' => array(
            '0' => array(),
            '1' => array(),
            '2' => array(),
            ),
        'area2' => array(
            '0' => array(),
            '1' => array(),
            '2' => array(),
            )
         )
      )
  );

foreach( $data as $key => $array )
{
    foreach( $array as $time => $areas )
    {
        foreach( $areas as $index => $area )
        {
            $data[$key][$time][$index] = count( $area );
        }

    }
}

var_dump( $data );
```

Returning

```
array(1) { [6]=> array(1) { ["00:01"]=> array(2) { ["area1"]=> int(3) ["area2"]=> int(3) } } }
```

Basically, all solutions use the same method: iteration!

Answer (score 0):

Use sizeof() function to get the size... And for dynamic array user foreach() function and inside that use foreach so it will give you the size of each array